# 2D diagonal movement using Rigidbody2D

Tags: unity, c#

I have a problem with 2d player movement, as I am unable to move on the Y-axis. Yet, the movement on the X-axis is working as intended.

Below, you can see my code:

```
public Sprite directionUp;
public Sprite directionDown;
public Sprite directionLeft;
public Sprite directionRight;

public float speed = 0.1f;
public byte direction = 0; //0 - up, 1 - right, 2 - down, 3 - left

private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
private Sprite[] directionArray;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    directionArray = new Sprite[]{ directionUp, directionDown, directionLeft, directionRight };
    if(directionArray[0] != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = directionArray[0];
}

// Update is called once per frame  
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad7))
    {
        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + new Vector2(-1f, 1f));

        if (directionArray[0] != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = directionArray[2];
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad9))
    {
        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + new Vector2(1f, 1f));

        if (directionArray[0] != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = directionArray[3];
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad1))
    {
        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + new Vector2(-1f, -1f));

        if (directionArray[0] != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = directionArray[2];
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad3))
    {
        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + new Vector2(1f, -1f));

        if (directionArray[0] != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = directionArray[3];
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad8))
    {
        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + new Vector2(0f, 1f));

        if (directionArray[0] != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = directionArray[0];
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad2))
    {
        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + new Vector2(0f, -1f));

        if (directionArray[0] != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = directionArray[1];
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad4))
    {
        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + new Vector2(-1f, 0f));

        if (directionArray[0] != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = directionArray[2];
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad6))
    {
        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + new Vector2(1f, 0f));

        if (directionArray[0] != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = directionArray[3];
    }
}
```

By the way, please keep in mind I am quite new to Unity.

EDIT 1///////////////////////

I have attached the entire script, some of the variables are unused right         now(was testing other methods of movement).

I tried to both Keypad - 1, 3, 6, 9, as well as the combinations which I didn't get to work yet (but this is off-topic and I will look into it once I will get the Y-axis to move).

Thanks, Zryw

Comment: Put the whole script.

Comment: Are you trying to go diagonal by holding two keys at once, or by pressing some seperate "diagonal motion" key

Comment: Don't edit solutions to your question. Instead, just post the solution as an answer, and don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I posted the answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution; it turned out to be a beginner's mistake. I locked the Y-axis in the Rigidbody2D component (to prevent the gravity effect pulling my character downwards all the time). I unchecked that and set the Gravity Scale to 0 and it is working!